# DependencySQL, weird behavior on update

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, sqldependency

I'm trying to use SQLDependency in my WPF application.

I have 2 different behavior, depending on how i update the database

The behavior 1 (Update from database) :

- On first database change (customer update) -> The soft receive the notification, the client list is updated.
- On second database change (customer update), the soft receive the notification, but the query result isn't updated.
- If the database change is "create customer" i receive the notification with ne new customer

The Behavior 2 (Changes from soft):

- I select one customer, from the customer list and update it. I receive a notification and the customer list is updated. If i re-update the save row, i still receive the notification but the query result isn't updated.
- But ! If i update another customer and change it, i can do it multiple time, the query results are ok ! only the first one bug.(from database, after the first one, i receive the notification, but query result isn't updated anyway)

  Code :

  ```
      #region Updater
  private IQueryable iCustomerquery = null;
  private ImmediateNotificationRegister<Customer> notification = null;
  RDatabase ctx = new RDatabase();

  void createCustomerRefreshQuery()
  {

      // Create the query.
      iCustomerquery = from p in ctx.Customers select p;

      notification = new ImmediateNotificationRegister<Customer>(ctx, iCustomerquery);
      notification.OnChanged += NotificationOnChanged;

  }


  /// <summary>
  /// When changed the data, the method will be invoked.
  /// </summary>
  void NotificationOnChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      System.Windows.Application app = System.Windows.Application.Current;
      app.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(UpdateCustomer), null);


  }

  void UpdateCustomer()
  {


      if (CanRequestNotifications())
      {
          Console.WriteLine("UPDATE");

          try
          {
              var customers = (iCustomerquery as DbQuery<Customer>).ToList();
              ClientList.Clear();
              foreach (var customer in customers)
              {

                  ClientList.Add(customer);
                  OnPropertyChanged("ClientList");

              }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              if (ex.InnerException != null)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + "(" + ex.InnerException.Message + ")");
              }
              else
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
              }
          }
      }
      //iCustomerquery = from p in ctx.Customers select p;

  }


  private bool CanRequestNotifications()
  {
      // In order to use the callback feature of the
      // SqlDependency, the application must have
      // the SqlClientPermission permission.
      try
      {
          SqlClientPermission perm =
              new SqlClientPermission(
              PermissionState.Unrestricted);

          perm.Demand();

          return true;
      }
      catch (SecurityException se)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(se.Message, "Permission Error");
          return false;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(e.Message, "Error");
          return false;
      }
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// Stop SqlDependency.
  /// </summary>
  private void StopSqlDependency(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      try
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Stop sql dependency");
          if (notification != null)
          {
              notification.Dispose();
              notification = null;
          }
      }
      catch (ArgumentException ex)
      {
          //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Paramter Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          if (ex.InnerException != null)
          {
              Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + "(" + ex.InnerException.Message + ")", "Failed to Stop SqlDependency");
          }
          else
          {
              Console.WriteLine(ex.Message, "Failed to Stop SqlDependency");
          }
      }
  }


  #endregion
  ```

I used this sample from msdn

ImmediateNotificationRegister :

```
    public class ImmediateNotificationRegister<TEntity> : IDisposable
    where TEntity : class
{
    private SqlConnection connection = null;
    private SqlCommand command = null;
    private IQueryable iquery = null;
    private ObjectQuery oquery = null;

    // Summary:
    //     Occurs when a notification is received for any of the commands associated
    //     with this ImmediateNotificationRegister object.
    public event EventHandler OnChanged;
    private SqlDependency dependency = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of ImmediateNotificationRegister class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="query">an instance of ObjectQuery is used to get connection string and 
    /// command string to register SqlDependency nitification. </param>
    public ImmediateNotificationRegister(ObjectQuery query)
    {
        try
        {
            this.oquery = query;

            QueryExtension.GetSqlCommand(oquery, ref connection, ref command);

            BeginSqlDependency();
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Paramter cannot be null", "query", ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(
                "Fails to initialize a new instance of ImmediateNotificationRegister class.", ex);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of ImmediateNotificationRegister class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">an instance of DbContext is used to get an ObjectQuery object</param>
    /// <param name="query">an instance of IQueryable is used to get ObjectQuery object, and then get  
    /// connection string and command string to register SqlDependency nitification. </param>
    public ImmediateNotificationRegister(DbContext context, IQueryable query)
    {
        try
        {
            this.iquery = query;

            // Get the ObjectQuery directly or convert the DbQuery to ObjectQuery.
            oquery = QueryExtension.GetObjectQuery<TEntity>(context, iquery);

            QueryExtension.GetSqlCommand(oquery, ref connection, ref command);

            BeginSqlDependency();
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            if (ex.ParamName == "context")
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Paramter cannot be null", "context", ex);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Paramter cannot be null", "query", ex);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(
                "Fails to initialize a new instance of ImmediateNotificationRegister class.", ex);
        }
    }

    private void BeginSqlDependency()
    {
        // Before start the SqlDependency, stop all the SqlDependency.
        SqlDependency.Stop(QueryExtension.GetConnectionString(oquery));
        SqlDependency.Start(QueryExtension.GetConnectionString(oquery));

        RegisterSqlDependency();
    }

    private void RegisterSqlDependency()
    {
        if (command == null || connection == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("command and connection cannot be null");
        }

        // Make sure the command object does not already have
        // a notification object associated with it.
        command.Notification = null;

        // Create and bind the SqlDependency object to the command object.
        dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
        dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(DependencyOnChange);

        // After register SqlDependency, the SqlCommand must be executed, or we can't 
        // get the notification.
        RegisterSqlCommand();
    }

    private void DependencyOnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Move the original SqlDependency event handler.
        SqlDependency dependency = (SqlDependency)sender;
        dependency.OnChange -= DependencyOnChange;

        if (OnChanged != null)
        {
            OnChanged(this, null);
        }

        // We re-register the SqlDependency.
        RegisterSqlDependency();
    }

    private void RegisterSqlCommand()
    {
        if (connection != null && command != null)
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Releases all the resources by the ImmediateNotificationRegister.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected void Dispose(Boolean disposed)
    {
        if (disposed)
        {
            if (StopSqlDependency())
            {
                if (command != null)
                {
                    command.Dispose();
                    command = null;
                }

                if (connection != null)
                {
                    connection.Dispose();
                    connection = null;
                }

                OnChanged = null;
                iquery = null;
                dependency.OnChange -= DependencyOnChange;
                dependency = null;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the notification of SqlDependency.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>If be success, returns true;If fails, throw the exception</returns>
    public Boolean StopSqlDependency()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlDependency.Stop(QueryExtension.GetConnectionString(oquery));
            return true;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null.", "query", ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Fails to Stop the SqlDependency in the ImmediateNotificationRegister class.", ex);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The SqlConnection is got from the Query.
    /// </summary>
    public SqlConnection Connection
    { get { return connection; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// The SqlCommand is got from the Query.
    /// </summary>
    public SqlCommand Command
    { get { return command; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// The ObjectQuery is got from the Query.
    /// </summary>
    public ObjectQuery Oquery
    { get { return oquery; } }
}
```

The query extension :

```
    public static class QueryExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Return the ObjectQuery directly or convert the DbQuery to ObjectQuery.
    /// </summary>
    public static ObjectQuery GetObjectQuery<TEntity>(DbContext context, IQueryable query)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        if (query is ObjectQuery)
            return query as ObjectQuery;

        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Paramter cannot be null", "context");

        // Use the DbContext to create the ObjectContext
        ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
        // Use the DbSet to create the ObjectSet and get the appropriate provider.
        IQueryable iqueryable = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>() as IQueryable;
        IQueryProvider provider = iqueryable.Provider;

        // Use the provider and expression to create the ObjectQuery.
        return provider.CreateQuery(query.Expression) as ObjectQuery;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use ObjectQuery to get SqlConnection and SqlCommand.
    /// </summary>
    public static void GetSqlCommand(ObjectQuery query, ref SqlConnection connection, ref SqlCommand command)
    {
        if (query == null)
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Paramter cannot be null", "query");

        if (connection == null)
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(QueryExtension.GetConnectionString(query));
        }

        if (command == null)
        {
            command = new SqlCommand(QueryExtension.GetSqlString(query), connection);

            // Add all the paramters used in query.
            foreach (ObjectParameter parameter in query.Parameters)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Name, parameter.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use ObjectQuery to get the connection string.
    /// </summary>
    public static String GetConnectionString(ObjectQuery query)
    {
        if (query == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Paramter cannot be null", "query");
        }

        EntityConnection connection = query.Context.Connection as EntityConnection;
        return connection.StoreConnection.ConnectionString;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use ObjectQuery to get the Sql string.
    /// </summary>
    public static String GetSqlString(ObjectQuery query)
    {
        if (query == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Paramter cannot be null", "query");
        }

        string s = query.ToTraceString();

        return s;
    }

}
```

**Update 1 :**
I didn't do the following should i ?

CREATE QUEUE CustomerChangeMessages;

CREATE SERVICE CustomerChangeNotifications
  ON QUEUE CustomerChangeMessages
([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification]);

Comment: That link is no longer valid

Answer (score 0):

I feel like one of 2 things is happening here, 1. You are removing the event handler prematurely, or 2 firing the primary trigger is invalidating the dependent trigger some how so it never fires.

Also your issue could be to do with all of the starting and stopping of the of the SqlDependency, anytime I have seen SqlDependency used, and when I have used it myself, its been started at the application start and stopped in application end, and the event handlers and recreation of the trigger itself has been used to manipulate firing.

A couple things I would try, (I am kinda guessing here because it is unclear what the issue is you are trying to resolve) 
1. Move your start and stop to app start and app end 
2. You could also recreate the all of the triggers whenever any are fired since they are dependent on each other.